# Best practices for querying facebook

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-fql, fan-page

I am interested in querying data from the FQL tables which are listed under the Facebook FQL references. I understand that some piece of information is available to the public whereas some other is not.

I am looking to start working on a project which requires gathering data for Fan Pages. This will include number of likes, who liked the page, posts, responses, etc. Also possibly I will be looking into demographics about the users.

I was reading that since being a fan of a page doesn't automatically mean that you have full access into the profile of a user. Somebody said that a good idea is to create a separate FB Application which will request permission for reading data from fans. But again, I don't like this idea. Nobody would install an application without motivation like that.

So, what is the best practice to do that?

Any pointers to start looking would be appreciated.

Thank you,

George

Comment: @Giogroc: Your question title and question are irrelevant. You want to query facebook and don't want to install app.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you answered your own question.  If you want the permission to query for things that you can only query after the user has granted you permission, you'll have to make an app to do that and get people to install your app.  Otherwise you'll only be able to grab things that are publicly available and don't require permissions.

Comment: So is the only way to be granted permission to a user's data by installing an application? Any other ways to "request" for this permission?

Comment: Yes, I just need to confirm that this is the best practice, or to express it even better, it's the only way to be granted permission by the user to read his/her data.